# On a site leaderboard, how are the nine hats shown for participants with more than nine chosen?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

When I look at the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/mathematica.stackexchange.com) for the Mathematica site where I have been awarded 13 hats, nine of these hats are shown. I don't see any particular pattern to the ones that show up. How are they selected from set that I have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have strong empirical evidence that they are shown in order of rarity (on the specific site). The leftmost one is the rarest.

The best example is that further down the list, for people with nine or less hats, the Just Here For The Hat is shown as the last one, i.e. the most common one.

The order of hats is slightly different from site to site, so I guess it's not the overall rarity, but site specific rarity. <s>We'll need a Stack Overflow developer to confirm this.</s> My observations have been confirmed by [balpha ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288792/on-a-site-leaderboard-how-are-the-nine-hats-shown-for-participants-with-more-th/288793?noredirect=1#comment937519_288793).

Comment: This is correct.