# Add ability to see who has a certain hat

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Can a search bar/link/button/whatever be added, to search who has a hat? That is, something like this:

[image: Profile hat stats]

Or maybe in the description on the Winter Bash main page:

[image: Winter Bash main page stats]

Or both!

These links would take you to a page similar to the site leaderboards, but show everybody who has that hat. Possibly sorted by date earned, how many other hats, how many sites earned on, etc.

Comment: Coincidently, that would be awfully useful for figuring out what actions trigger secret hats . . .

Comment: @JonEricson true, but I think most of the secret hats can be figured out by people saying "I got this hat" in the chatroom for hats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jon Ericson noted in a comment, this would make it much easier to collect data about secret hats, which would break their secrets much earlier.  I kind of like having some mysteries; I still have no idea how I got one of my secret hats and that's ok.  If I figure it out, cool.  If not, they'll tell me in a couple weeks.

However, there *is* some aggregate data that I'd like to see, that I think doesn't break secret hats too badly:

- First, I'm still looking for [a way to see which hats I've earned on a particular site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246553/162102).  Not just the first nine, which I can get from the leaderboard, but all of them.  Combined with the ability to wear different hats on different sites, this would let me wear locally-earned hats without having to manually iterate through the hats.  This could be a filter in the hat box -- a checkbox for "show only hats earned on this site", near the other checkboxes.
- Second, I'd like to know which are the popular (or rare) hats on a particular site.  Show me, for a single site, the number of each hat that's been earned.  I don't have a particular use in mind for this data; I just think it would be interesting, both for sites looking "within" and for comparing sites.  This could be a link on the leaderboard.

Comment: As for rarity, the order of hats on the per-site leaderboards [are ordered by rarity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288793/307988), no hard numbers I know, but it gives you an idea.

Comment: @Cai it gives an idea for the rarest nine, at least.  It'd be nice to know about the rest of them too, and numbers (e.g. the number of people with "I am your father" sets a floor for meta activity; just how high or low is it?).

Comment: Well users further down still give you the order of the less rare ones, but I completely agree specific numbers would be nice